# Prove that in presence of many goods, the law of DMRS implies that at least one good must be a net substitute for any other good

Tags: microeconomics, self-study

I've been reading a book where the author claims that "if there are two goods they are always net substitutes. Along an indifference curve an increase in price of good 2 leads to less of good 2 and more of good 1 being consumed when utility is maximized. When there are more than two goods, the law of diminishing marginal rate of substitution implies that at least one good must be a net substitute for any other good." 

The first part can be proved easily using graphs, it's the second that I couldn't prove mathematically.

Source of the quotation has been attached [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=pi4JBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=net%20substitutes%20more%20than%20two%20goods%20law%20of%20diminishing%20marginal%20rate%20of%20substitution%20implies%20that%20at%20least%20one%20of%20the%20goods%20must%20be%20a%20net%20substitute%20for%20any%20other%20good&source=bl&ots=rvPf6etHY5&sig=AoDLRTE3tZYYM5r9KaFgKFIpx5Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFzpWgzpndAhXbe30KHbbRBlUQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=net%20substitutes%20more%20than%20two%20goods%20law%20of%20diminishing%20marginal%20rate%20of%20substitution%20implies%20that%20at%20least%20one%20of%20the%20goods%20must%20be%20a%20net%20substitute%20for%20any%20other%20good&f=false), Pg-104.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is the definition of the "law of DMRS", but I think what the author meant is summarized in these lines of MWG:

> Proposition 3.G.2: suppose that $u(\cdot)$ is a continuous utility function representing a locally nonsatiated and strictly convex preference relation $\succsim$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^L_+$. Suppose also that $h(\cdot, u)$ [the hicksian demand function] is continuously differentiable at $(p, u)$, and denote its $L\times L$ derivative matrix [with respect to each $p$] by $D_p h(p, u)$. Then
>
> 1. $D_p h(p, u)$ is a negative semidefinite matrix.
> 2. $D_p h(p, u) p = 0$

Well, 1 implies that the elements of the main diagonal of the matrix are all non positive, i.e. $\frac{\partial h_l (p, u)}{\partial p_l} \leq 0$ for each $l$.

We say that two goods are substitutes if $\frac{\partial h_l (p, u)}{\partial p_k} \geq 0$ (a positive variation in the price of $k$ implies an increase in the compensated demand of $l$).

Part 2 of the proposition says that $D_p h(p, u) p = 0$. But as $\frac{\partial h_l (p, u)}{\partial p_l} \leq 0$, for every $l$ we must have a good $m$ such that $\frac{\partial h_l (p, u)}{\partial p_m} \geq 0$, which means exactly that every good has a substitute.